# Computer turns off abruptly on heavy CPU load

Tags: cpu, shutdown

I have:

Motherboard: DG35EC
Processor: Intel Dual Core E2180 , 2.00 GHz
Hard disk: 500 GB - ST3500418AS
RAM: 1 GB

For 2 weeks now, I am facing this strange issue. Whenever I run some heavy programs simultaneously computer suddenly turns off after some time. For example, before posting this question, I was running Opera with many tabs open and started installing huge software. While working in opera, I noticed that the system is getting heavy utilization due that installation.  Before the installation completes,  it turned off suddenly. 
I cannot just do a single task at a time, but after failing installation third time, I have a plan to run it after closing all other programs.
.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like your CPU is overheating and shutting down automatically to avoid damage.

I would check the airflow in your computer's case - make sure that cables are not restricting it.  Make sure that the CPU cooler is not clogged up with dust and make sure that it is properly seated on the CPU.

Comment: These days weather temperature is near 19-29 degree centigrade. Also one side of computer case is open and i removed the front covers where CD/DVD rom is palced. Just to make sure that processor dont get heatup.

Comment: I used coretemp http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/ and it says the temperature of cores about 45-59 degree while i am installing the software in background. How to keep it cool :(

Comment: It reached 63 :(, i was totally unaware of it. How to keep it damn cool, it started 2 weeks ago. Before that it was all fine.

Comment: @LifeH2O: By taking the side panel off, you would most probably be making it worse, as the case is designed to have the air travel through it, from the front to the rear.  The temperatures in my case go up when I take the side panel off.

Comment: My case was a cheaper one, and the system sits there in a place like shown in this image http://www.karlals.com/furniture/catalog/schoolbiz/images/tables/Computer-Table.jpg I thought taking the side panel off will make more space for air, the backside of table is covered and i have made small holes in it.

Comment: @LifeH2O:  No wonder it is overheating, with high ambient temperature, you disassembling the case and then putting it in a cupboard!

Comment: But the strange thing is that i am using this system with same and (even worse in summer) conditions  from 2 years. And it started now from a few weaks.

Comment: @LifeH2O: There may be dust in the cooler and fans, your machine may be under a heavier workload, and the thermal paste inbetween the CPU and cooler may have degraded, or the cooler may no longer contacting the CPU properly.  What is clear is that your CPU is overheating.

Comment: Since you have the case open, you can literally get a table fan and just point it into the case, right at the CPU. In addition to what jason404 says, it's also possible your CPU cooler fan is failing and not turning fast enough any more.  My BIOS lets me check the RPMs--does yours?

Comment: How much heat it can bear, i am running a test and it reached 83 degree while i am writing this in opera. No turn off yet. Moreover as only opera is running and a tool http://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=2 i am not feeling any workload.

Comment: @CarlF In my BIOS>Advanced>Hardware Monitoring>Fan Speed was 1875. In Fan control i changed Processor Zone to 'Aggressive'

Comment: Removing covers and opening drive bays can make a CPU run *hotter*.  This is because the manufacturer has gone through some trouble to craft the airflow into and out of the case to move the most amount of air possible over the CPU.  If you disrupt the airflow pattern by opening new holes, the CPU can get *less* airflow even though there is more airflow overall.

Comment: LifeH2O, many CPU fans are designed to run at 2400-3000 RPM.  One wonders if replacing the fan (and thermal paste) would solve your cooling problem.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a CPU overheating problem.

Running Prime 95 along with a CPU monitoring application, such as http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/ will let you know if your CPU is the problem.

Prime 95 is a stress testing tool. It works by making your PC calculate  Mersenne prime numbers.

Run Prime 95's Torture test while monitoring the CPU temperature, and see if it rises too high, until the PC eventually shuts off.

According to http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/143/5 the maximum temperature for your CPU is 73.2C.

pd: Prime 95 download links http://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=2

Comment: I used coretemp alcpu.com/CoreTemp and it says the temperature of cores about 45-59 degree while i am installing the software in background. and then it reached 65 and i blew some air with my mouth and came down to 53-56 for some time. How to keep this damn thing cool?

Comment: I ran this test and temperature reached 83 degree but i am still multitasking.

Comment: Then it seems the CPU is not the problem. Could be, as Amir pointed out, a faulty RAM module.

Answer (score 3):

It can also be memory error. Run windows memory test at start up. Or use [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) ISO.

Comment: it is available on CD, any other downloadable tool?

Comment: If you have cd for Windows 7 or Vista I'm sure that installation CD has a memory tool built-in.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem and it was because the thermal paste that came with the board/cpu combo I bought used was insufficient. I ran load tests before I fixed it and the temperature kept climbing up to 90C and then turning off, but after I put new paste on the CPU, now it sits around 54C on the same load. So if you forgot to put paste on or you bought a used board, you might want to check for that.